# Any other Ad SDK for WinRT (Windows 8) other than AdCenter?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

Any other Ad SDK for WinRT (Windows 8) other than AdCenter?
This is with C# and XAML.

Anyone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [AdDuplex](https://www.adduplex.com/) cross-promotion network specifically targeted at Windows 8 and Windows Phone.